# Correct fd for a shell prompt

Tags: c, shell, unix, file-descriptor

I'm making a custom shell in C and I wonder on which fd I should write my prompts.

```
mycoolshell $
```

Looking into other classic shells, I found that `dash` uses STDERR for its prompts. `csh` and `tcsh` use STDOUT. For `bash`, `zsh` and BSD `sh` I wasn't able to find anything. I used

```sh
% dash 2>file
echo qwe
echo qwe
% cat file
(dashprompt$)
(dashprompt$)
```

to check dash's prompt fd. Same with csh with `csh 1>file` but I was unlucky with the other ones.

Is there a standard or POSIX fd for this? Is it ok to use STDIN?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20826/which-stream-does-bash-write-its-prompt-to

Comment: I think there is not correct one. Interactive shell in any case try to get console. if you are looking for POSIX, just look at the standard (which you must do, it you are implementing a new shell). austin group may answer better (shell writers usually hand there: there is always something to learn, and to fix)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi "Must" is a bit strong. You don't *have* to make a shell POSIX-compatible.

Comment: @chepner: right, OTOH one should learn from past. No need to implement a POSIX, but you get a list of problems, how to decompose the problem (evaluation, different steps, etc.), etc. Like if one want to implement a new language, he should master one existing language. So yes, it is not a must, but I think still "highly recommended".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to be Posix compatible, you'll need to write the prompt to `stderr`. (See the specification of the `PS1` environment variable, below.)

Regardless of strict Posix compatibility, `stdin` is definitely not correct, since it may not allow write operations. `stdout` is also not a good idea, since it is usually line-buffered. Some shells (including `zsh`, I believe) write the prompt to a file descriptor connected to the current terminal (such as `/dev/tty`) which is probably what `stderr` is opened as if not redirected, although it is not necessarily the same file descriptor. But using `/dev/tty` or equivalent is non-standard.

The prompt is only printed if the shell is *interactive*. A shell is interactive, according to Posix, if it is invoked in one of two ways:

> If the `-i` option is present, or if there are no operands and the shell's standard input and standard error are attached to a terminal, the shell is considered to be interactive. ([`sh` utility, Options](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_04))

Clearly, you wouldn't want the shell to spew out prompts if you are using it to execute a script. So you need some mechanism to tell if the shell is being used interactively or as a script processor; Posix's requirement seems reasonably accurate. (See the [`isatty()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html) library function to see one way to do this test.)

That also shows why your test failed to capture the prompt when `stderr` was redirected to a file. Redirecting `stderr` causes the shell to be non-interactive so there will not be a prompt. To do the test properly, you need to force the shell to be interactive using the `-i` option.

Posix requires that the prompt be modifiable by changing the value of the `PS1` environment variable. Here's what Posix has to say, including the requirement that the prompt be printed to `stderr`: (emphasis added)

> `PS1`
>
> Each time an interactive shell is ready to read a command, the value of this variable shall be subjected to parameter expansion and **written to standard error.** The default value shall be "$ ". For users who have specific additional implementation-defined privileges, the default may be another, implementation-defined value. The shell shall replace each instance of the character '!' in PS1 with the history file number of the next command to be typed. Escaping the '!' with another '!' (that is, "!!" ) shall place the literal character '!' in the prompt. ([Shell command language, Shell Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03))

Most shells allow a much richer set of substitutions in `PS1`. But the fact that the value is subject to parameter expansion allows extensive customisation. That means that (unlike usual variable expansion) parameter and command references appearing in the value of the `PS1` variable are expanded every time the prompt is printed.

Comment: It looks like you are exactly right, but you seem to have buried the lead.  It would be nice to call more attention to the fact that the POSIX documentation around `PS1` says that its expanded value written specifically to `stderr`.

Comment: @johnBollinger: That's why I put it in the lede. I'll try to highlight the connection a bit more, though.

Comment: `bash` writes the prompt to standard error; you can confirm by running `bash 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: @chepner: Proves nothing. If you redirect stderr to `/dev/null`, the shell is no longer interactive and no prompt is written anywhere.

Comment: OK, try `bash -i 2> /dev/null`, which forces an interactive shell.

Comment: @chepner: So try `bash -i 2>/tmp/foo` and see if `/tmp/foo` ends up containing a prompt. (It does contain the text you typed into stdin because readline echoes to stderr).

Comment: @rici It does, along with the echoed input.

Comment: @chepner: It's zsh which writes directly to the tty. Sorry about the memory error and thanks for the correction. (Confirmed with `strace`).